# Visual C++ 2010 "system property sheet" and "user property sheet", key difference?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm reading Inside [MSBuild 2nd-edition](http://www.oreilly.com/pub/pr/2727) from MS Press. When it comes to chapter 10 introducing the concept of "user property sheet" and "system property sheet", I come up with a question: What determines whether a property sheet is "user" or "system"?

As told by the book(p284), user property sheet and system property sheet are displayed with different icons inside Visual Studio 2010 IDE.

[image]

So,

- *Upgrade from VC 6.0* and *Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user* are "user".
- *Application* and *Core Windows Libraries* are "system".

I first thought that

- .props from **%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0** are "user "
- .props from **C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0** are "system"

but that's not the case, because *Upgrade from VC 6.0* is from **C:\Program Files (x86)** while it is a user property sheet.

Then what's the key determination factor?

Comment: Don't have VS2010 to test, but is it possible that the ones called 'system' are those which are imported 'indirectly' by the project (i.e. via an Import in the project itself but via an Import somewhere in Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props or Microsoft.Cpp.props), while the ones called 'user' are imported directly in the project? Open the project in a text editor and look for Import statements to confirm this. Also note in later version the visual distincation in VS has been removed.

Comment: Oh yes. The .vcxproj file has ``<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)Microsoft.CPP.UpgradeFromVC60.props" />`` in it, a direct import. So do you mean  **Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props** and **Microsoft.Cpp.props** are special names recognized by VS IDE to be considered "system"?

Comment: Not sure.. I'd rather think Application and Core Windows Libraries would be the special names then. Or else Microsoft.Cpp.props is a special name and because Application/... are nested inside that one they are also considered 'System'. Or another possibility: because the property sheets's names start with Microsoft.Cpp and/or are in subdirectories of msbuild/microsoft.cpp they are treated like that. Endless possibilities :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, maybe the author has answered it as I have guessed, but in a vague and ambiguous way. On page 284, there is:

> The System Property Sheets are pulled into a Visual C++ project via
>   the following two imports, which you can find at the beginning of your
>   project file (note that these are not successive lines in the project
>   file; they are separated by other lines).
>
> ```
> <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
> <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
> ```

[image]

The reader has two ways to interpret this statement:

1. It emphasizes how "system property sheets" gets into .vcxproj. But the definition of "system property sheets" is stated elsewhere.
2. The two specially named(`Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props` and `Microsoft.Cpp.props`) import statements defines what is called "system property sheet". (very implicit)

Perhaps the authour means both.